# Postgres Slow join with where clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I already making index on both table. But its still pretty slow. And its so fast without the where clause.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE  SELECT date, a , b, c FROM t1 JOIN t2 using (date, a)  where date = current_date
;

Nest2d Loop  (cost=0.71..12.75 rows=1 width=22) (actual time=0.343..50925.262 rows=87956 loops=1)
  Join Filt2r: (t1.a = t2.a)
  Rows Removed by Join Filt2r: 262988440
  ->  Index Scan using t1_date_idx1 on t1 t1  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=15) (actual time=0.022..20.240 rows=87956 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (date = CURRENT_DATE)
  ->  Index Scan using t2_date_idx on t2 t2  (cost=0.29..4.30 rows=1 width=15) (actual time=0.005..0.353 rows=2991 loops=87956)
        Index Cond: (date = CURRENT_DATE)
Planning time: 0.151 ms
Execution time: 50930.327 ms
```

Without where clause:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE  SELECT date, a , b, c FROM t1 JOIN t2 using (date, a) 
;

Hash Join  (cost=349.55..11993.24 rows=182123 width=22) (actual time=4.741..61.881 rows=182123 loops=1)
  Hash Cond: ((t1.date = t2.date) AND (t1.a = t2.a))
  ->  Seq Scan on t1 t1  (cost=0.00..8001.23 rows=182123 width=15) (actual time=2.921..17.651 rows=182123 loops=1)
  ->  Hash  (cost=259.82..259.82 rows=5982 width=15) (actual time=1.765..1.765 rows=5982 loops=1)
        Buckets: 8192  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 350kB
        ->  Seq Scan on t2 t2  (cost=0.00..259.82 rows=5982 width=15) (actual time=0.115..0.908 rows=5982 loops=1)
Planning time: 0.280 ms
Execution time: 66.400 ms
```

Comment: can you try `ANALYZE t1;` and `ANALYZE t2;` and try your query with `WHERE` clause again?  The index estimates appear to be incorrect

Comment: Could you create a fiddle for us to play around? https://www.db-fiddle.com

Answer (score 0):

Thanks rickyen , After try "ANALYZE t1; and ANALYZE t2; ". It is much better.

```
Hash Join  (cost=233.44..7052.01 rows=87936 width=15) (actual time=0.936..31.488 rows=87956 loops=1)
  Hash Cond: (t1.a = t2.a)
  ->  Index Scan using t1_date_idx1 on t1  (cost=0.42..5499.81 rows=87965 width=15) (actual time=0.026..12.625 rows=87956 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (date = CURRENT_DATE)
  ->  Hash  (cost=195.63..195.63 rows=2991 width=8) (actual time=0.900..0.900 rows=2991 loops=1)
        Buckets: 4096  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 152kB
        ->  Index Scan using t2_date_idx on t2  (cost=0.29..195.63 rows=2991 width=8) (actual time=0.015..0.556 rows=2991 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (date = CURRENT_DATE)
Planning time: 0.171 ms
Execution time: 33.799 ms
```

Comment: Do you have an index on column "a" ? Or maybe even beter, a combined index on a and date: create index on t1(date,a); create index on t2(date,a);